# phantomjs - execute a Javascript function after page load and then output new changes

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I use phantomjs 2.1.1 and something is bothering me.
Here is the piece of code that I use for scraping a url and the html of the website is written into output.html file

```
page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open(url, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var content = page.content;
                fs.write("output.html", content, 'w');
            }, 40000); //40 seconds timeout
        }
    });
```

Now, I need to scrape its paginations too. The next pages are loaded by a javascript function page(2); or page(3); I tried to get it done using

```
 var pageinationOutput = page.evaluate(function (s) {
    page(2);
 });
 console.log(pageinationOutput); // I need the output made by the  `page(2);` call.

        page = require('webpage').create();
            page.open(url, function (status) {
                if (status !== 'success') {
                    console.log('Unable to load the address!');
                    phantom.exit();
                } else {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        var content = page.content;
                        fs.write("output.html", content, 'w');
                    }, 40000); //40 seconds timeout
                }
            });
```

But i am not getting any outputs for this.
How can I execute a JavaScript function after a page is finished loading and get the **new changes** that has happened to the website contents after the javascript exec, in this case website will call the next page (using ajax) after page(2); method call.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution myself but I am not sure whether it's the perfect way to do it.

Code:

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var content = page.content;
            fs.write("output.html", content, 'w');
            page.evaluate(function (cb) {
                window.page(2);
            });
            var waiter = window.setInterval(function () {
                var nextPageContent = page.evaluate(function (cb) {
                    return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
                });
                if (nextPageContent !== false) {
                    window.clearInterval(waiter);
                    fs.write("output-2.html", content, 'w');
                }
            }, 40000);//40 seconds timeout  

        }, 40000);//40 seconds timeout  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that gives PHP access to a browser. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS. It is also PhantomJS under the hood.

If you provided the URL i could make a working example. I need to know how you determine the last page. In the example i simply set it to 10.
I also need to know if the page buttons have an id attribute, If they dont no problem, we find another way to trigger them. But for this example I assume they do and to make it simple the ids will be page_2, page_3 ....

After downloading and setup you would simply use the following code:

```
$myUrl          = "http://www.example.com";
$windowObj      = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getBrowser('phantomjs')->getNewWindow($myUrl);

//now you can either retrieve the DOM for each page:
$doms = array();
//get the initial page DOM
$doms[]  = $windowObj->getDom();

$pageID   = "page_";
$lastPage = 10;
for ($i = 2; $i <= $lastPage; $i++) {
   $windowObj->mouseEventOnElement("[id=".$pageID. $i . "]", 'leftclick');
   $doms[]  = $windowObj->getDom();
}

//$doms now hold all the pages, so you can parse them.
```